# Saving Data from VB.Net Windows Forms in MS Access having error System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Data type mismatch in criteria expression.'

Tags: vb.net, forms, visual-studio, ms-access

```
str = "INSERT INTO Rent_Transaction ([Username], [Type], [Plate No], [Start Date], [End Date], [Total]) 
      VALUES('" & UsernameLog.Text & "','" & LabelType.Text & "','" & Plate.Text & "','" & StartDate.Text & "','" & EndDate.Text & "','" & Total.Text & "')"
con.Open()
cmd = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

'represents sql and db connection that are used to fill the data set and update the data source
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)

'to check if there are any matches in the table 
da.Fill(ds, "Rent_Transaction")

con.Close()
con.Dispose()
```

error is in the cmd.ExecuteNonQuery. I can't save the data in the ms access

Comment: Don't use string concatenation to build SQL statements. Do it properly and use parameters and this issue will go away, along with several others. Read more [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/08/using-parameters-in-adonet.html).

Comment: Look at all those values passed to the database engine like the receiving fields are of type string. Evidently they are not. This is one of the many reasons to use parameters when you build sql code. Of course the worst problem is the Sql Injection problem

Comment: Another error in your code is the call to SqlDataAdapter.Fill. That call should be used when you want to _read_ from the database ( A select query is in the command) not when you want to insert/update or delete. Nevertheless the Fill call still executes the command passed and this will result in a double record inserted (the first by ExecuteNonQuery, the second by Fill)

Comment: Quick fix is to use # delimiter for date/time fields and apostrophe for text fields and nothing for number fields.

Comment: A quick fix that could be dangerous as the current query.

Comment: I tried to use the parameter but still has an error of Data Type mismatch in criteria expression

Comment: Can you post the datatable schema? What are exactly the database types expected by the table's fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here how I would execute the task to insert a record into your table:

```
Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(......)
    Dim str = "INSERT INTO Rent_Transaction ([Username], [Type], [Plate No], [Start Date], [End Date], [Total]) 
               VALUES(@name,@type,@plate, @init,@end,@total)"
    con.Open()
    Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str, con)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@name", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = UsernameLog.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@type", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = LabelType.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@plate", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = Plate.Text
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@init", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(StartDate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@end", OleDbType.Date).Value = Convert.ToDateTime(EndDate.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@total", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Total.Text)
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

The first change is the Using statement around the creation of the OleDbConnection. This will ensure a proper closing/disposal of the connection when the code exits the End Using. It is always the best course of action to do so even with local file based databases like MS-Access.

The second change is the query text, now we have a string that contains parameter placeholders. No more concatenation, no more quoting around variables, a lot clearer to read and understand construct.

The third change is the building of the parameters. As you can see, each parameter has a type defined that should match the type expected by the database table's fields. **Notice** how the values for the last three parameters are converted to the supposed type expected by the datatable. This way, we don't allow the database to execute a conversion by itself probably resulting in that 'type mismatch'.

Finally, all the code relative to the OleDbDataAdapter has been removed.

Comment: What is Convert.ToInt32? I tried the code and it had this error  'Failed to convert parameter value from a Int32 to a DateTime.'. I'm confused since you declare the Convert.ToInt32 with the Total but the error says Int32 to a DateTime

Comment: Oh wait i think it's because of the type

Comment: Aw, sorry, need to change the parameter type (copy/paste classic)

Comment: Also, keep in mind that those Convert.ToXXXX are a very rudimental way to convert _user input_ from a string to a specific type. They can raise exceptions if the input value is not in the format they expect. In particular DateTime is very brittle in this sense. It would be better to convert using DateTime.TryParseExact and send an error message to your user if something goes wrong.

Comment: What if it says 'You cannot add or change a record because a related record is required in table '?

Comment: This means that there is a relationship between this table and some other table. Some field is linked to the other table and you cannot insert a value here if the other table has not a matching value for that field

Comment: since you setting the types with OleDbType, then you can in most cases just assign the text box and casting will be done for you. So for both date, and those integers - you quite much are ok to just assign without the conversions - (I suppose it don't hurt). but as noted, you need ONE more column here - that is the column that has to be set to the PK id of the parent record - this looks to be a child table - and thus what column value you used/using to relate to the parent record of this table is missing.  As noted, we would need a screen cap of this table desing.